# Undergraduate algebra problem of field theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

I tried to solve but I couldn't. Can you solve this problem?

> 1. Let $F$ be a field and let $t$ be transcendental over $F$. Let $x\in F(t)$ and suppose $x\not\in F$. Prove that $F(t)$ is algebraic over $F(x)$.
>
>    If $x$ is expressed as a quotient of relatively prime polynomials, i.e. $x = \dfrac{f(t)}{g(t)}$, find $[F(t):F(x)]$ in terms of degrees of $f$ and $g$. Prove all assertions.

Using hint , i could solve it like below.Is it correct?

About problem 1

Let $h(X)=\dfrac{f(t)}{g(t)}g(X)-f(X)\in F(x)[X].$

then $h(t)=0.$

then $t$ is algebraic number over $F(x)$.

then $[F(t):F(x)]$ is finite dimension.

then $F(t)$ is algebraic over $F(x)$.

About problem 2

$h(X)$is minimal polinomial of $t$ over $F(x)$.

then $deg(h(X))=[F(t):F(x)]$

onthe other hand $deg(h(X))=max\{deg(f(X)),deg(g(X))\}$

then $[F(t):F(x)]=max\{deg(f(X)),deg(g(X))\}$

Comment: You should post your attempt while asking for help so that others can correct your work.

Comment: What did you try? I would try some simple cases. For instance, take $x = t^2$, $x = t^2 + t$, or $x = (t+1)/(t^2+1)$ and try to solve the problem. Then try to generalize.

Comment: Let  $G, H$ be fields with $G\subset H .$  If $a,b\in H$ are both algebraic over $G$ then so are $a\pm  b$ and $ab$ and $a^{-1}$ (if $a\ne 0).$ .... So if $t$ is algebraic over $F[x]$ and if $p,q$ are polynomials with co-efficients in $F$, and $q(t)\ne  0$ then the co-efficients of $p$ and q belong to $F[x],$ so $p(t)/q(t)$ is algebraic over $F[x]$.

Comment: You still need to prove that $h(X)$ is irreducible over $F(x)$. This is not trivial. Also you should make it clear for yourself that indeed $F(t) = F(x)[t]$.